# Video Editing - Text Effect Font

Tags: video-sequence-editor, edit-mode, effects, text-editor

Can we change the Text Effect(Video editing) font as of 2.79 version?

If not, how can a text created by Text Editor be pulled into the Video Timeline Editor?

Thanks,
Anand

Comment: These are 2 separate questions. 1) how do I change the VSE font - you can't yet. 2) how do I get text from text tool into VSE display - text tool does not export text.

Comment: @rob I like the workaround. The difficulty is the implementation. Do you mean created a 3D TEXT in default view using orthographic camere and save it as a Scene. Then add that Scene into the VSE? Well how do you add the existing scene into the VSE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I use the fact that Blender can have multiple scenes each with wildly different settings/setups/objects.

Click the plus sign at the top of the screen next to Scene. 
[image]

Select New and rename it to something relevant.
[image]
note that it resets to the Blender defaults, in this case I Blender Render not Cycles, so remember to update it.

Add a Text object and add a camera. set the rotation to 0,0,0 and position it above your text.
[image]

Set the Camera to Orthographic.
[image]

There are various ways of getting the Text lit.

I usually add a Lamp set to Sun and pointing directly down. Change the Strength to 4 to get a strong contrast.
[image]

Depending on what outcome you want you can either set the background colour or set as Transparent.

[image]

Now in the VSE you can add a new Scene as a video strip
[image]

Then set the Strip settings to your new Scene
[image]

final set the Strip Blend to Alpha Over and the Alpha Mode to Transparent
[image]

When you render the strips will be combined.
[image]

Here the default Scene contains the default Cube with the default Lighting and our Title Text Scene is Rendered and placed in front of it.

The great thing about this technique is that you can do really cool animations with the text. From basic scrolling to bouncing to 3D manipulations. And you can do this with as many scenes as you need.

Comment: Super set of instructions. I followed them and was able to achieve the menitoned results. My Sun does NOT have a strength- I am using Blender 2.78. And how do I change the FONT type?

Comment: Sorry missed a step. When adding a lamp you need to click "Use Nodes" button to see the strength. When you add a Text object from the Add menu you can Tab into Edit mode and change the text and a large selection of tools for Fonts will appear. This includes the Font name itself and size, line spacing, alignment etc.

Comment: Thanks a ton. These steps was really helpful, not just in terms of VSE and adding different types of Font texts but also in creating 3D texts since I am absolutely a newbie in that area.